# Issue in converting class to class type

Tags: c++, loops

In below code I am converting a 24-hour clock to 12-hour clock.

In class `A` I am accepting the value from user and in class `B` I am doing the conversion logic.

If user enters a value greater than `12` only then I am changing the value of `c` to `1` but if the user enter a value less than `12` even then the value of `c` is changing to `1338`. Also for further analysis I added two more variables, `x` and `b`, in class `B` to see what happens to them. Inside the constructor I am initializing the value of `x` and `b` to `0` but while displaying them it shows `x=11585` and `b=1338`.

Kindly advise how are these values `c=1338` for value of time less than `12`, `x=11585` and `b=1338` are being assigned even after intializing them in the constructor.

[image: Program's output]

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class A
{
    public:
    int time;

    A()
    {
        time = 0;
    }

    void set()
    {
        cout<<"Enter time :"<<endl;
        cin>>time;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<"You entered : "<<time<<endl;
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    int c;
    int t;
    int x;
    int b;

    B()
    {
        c = 0;
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    B(A a1)
    {
        cout<<"x = "<<x<<" "<<"b = "<<b<<endl;

        if(a1.time > 12)
        {
            cout<<"inside if";
            c = 1;
            t = a1.time - 12;
        } 
        else
        {
            cout<<"inside else"<<endl;
            cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;
            t = a1.time;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        if(c==1)
        {
            cout<<"Time in 12 hours format is : "<<t <<"pm"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Time in 12 hours format is : "<<t <<"am"<<endl;
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    A a;
    B b;

    a.set();
    a.display();

    b = a;
    b.display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping though your code line by line with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor taking the `A` argument, you use `x`, `b`, and `c` *before* they are initialized. Those member variables will have *indeterminate* values, and even reading from them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The default constructor is *not* called automatically.

Either explicitly initialize the member variables, or "call" the default constructor:

```
B(A a1)
    : B()
{
    // The existing code...
}
```

---

On a couple of unrelated notes: You should probably make the constructor `explicit` so it's not a converting constructor; And you should probably pass the argument as a constant reference:

```
explicit B(A const& a1)
    : B()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In the main function on the third line I have called the default constructor.
So the values must be reflected.

Also the below code says B cannot be a base class of B.

I even tried writing B() as the first line in B(A a1) but still garbage values were shown.

B(A a1)
    : B()
{
    // The existing code...
}

Comment: @Geek *Because* the constructor with an argument is not `explicit` the assignment `b = a` is actually `b = B(a)`. I.e. a temporary `B` object is created using the constructor with an argument, which doesn't initialize the variables. This temporary object is then used in the implicitly created assignment operator (which copy the uninitialized variables), and then the temporary object is destructed. If you chained the default constructor you should not get uninitialized or random values.

Comment: @Geek With some fixes (like using the *standard* `<iostream>` (without the `.h` ending) and returning `int` from `main`) [I can not replicate your problem once I chain a call to the default constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4cc528cfcab29e2).